# sales_order_place_after not working magento 2

Tags: events, magento2, observers

I am trying to listen to this event sales_order_place_after in magento 2 , but after place order click nothings happen, (the same observer work when listning to another event like login).
Any idea for what's going on ?
Thanxs.

Comment: Could you add a bit more context?

Comment: Now the observer work for this event, I would like to retrieve checkout data but when I var_dump the observer I get nothing

Comment: $order = $observer->getEvent()->getData();
           
          $order_content = json_encode($order); I get {"order":{"_eavConfig":{}},"name":"sales_order_place_after"}

Comment: Hello hamza , I'm facing the same problem, Could you share what you did?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using the Observer in your module app\code\Vendorname\modulename\etc\frontend\events.xml -

```
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
    <observer name="mymodule_controller_success_action" instance="Vendorname\modulename\Observer\MyObserver"  />
</event>
```

and in app\code\Vendorname\modulename\MyObserver.php file add code -

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\mudulename\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Captcha\Observer\CaptchaStringResolver;

class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
      public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
     $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
     echo $orderId = $order->getId();
     $comment = $this->getRequest()->getParam('comment');

     print_r("Catched event succssfully !"); exit;

     echo "Do your Work Here";
    }

}
```